# What is the right place for bug reports on SE sites?

Tags: support, area-51

What is the right place for bug reports on SE sites that really deal with the SE engine? (E.g. reports of a [seemingly] broken view count)

The SE site's meta, or Meta.SO?

Answer (score 1):

MSO, although it's fairly common for users to post them on the site's meta since they often don't realize the site is part of a larger network. I usually leave a comment telling them about MSO with a link here

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance post on the site's meta, unless you are sure that the problem will be common to all sites. In that case post here.

With regard to your example - the view counts displayed on posts are quite heavily cached so will appear incorrect more often than not.

Comment: Cheers @Chris. In my case though, it's about an [exploding view count](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/826/view-counter-off-the-rocker)

Comment: @Pekka - that is different!